# Problem with Gin Gonic and Qor Admin: error 500 on heroku

Tags: go, heroku, go-gin, qor

I want to create an admin panel for my project and i used Qor admin with Gin. When i tested it on localhost it didnt cause any errors or exeptions, but when i commit it to heroku i`ll get 500 error; I use Gorm v1 as an ORM. How can i fix the error?

This is main project file is:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/qor/admin"
)

func main() {
    connect()

    Admin := admin.New(&admin.AdminConfig{DB: db})

    adminServer := http.NewServeMux()
    Admin.MountTo("/admin", adminServer)
    Admin.AddResource(&User{})

    app := gin.Default()
    //app.LoadHTMLGlob("views/*")
    app.MaxMultipartMemory = 140 << 20
    gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)

    Controller(app)

    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "5000"
    }

    app.Any("/admin/*resources", gin.WrapH(adminServer))
    app.Run(":" + port)
}
```

And what i get as a result when i try to open AP:
[And what i get as a result when i try to open AP:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0cbx.png)

Comment: Your code looks quite different from examples I've seen around https://doc.getqor.com/admin/integration.html can you try a simpler implementation and see if it fails? Also seems like the heroku tag should be added since it only happens with Heroku.

Comment: @Wolfgang i tried more simpler realization, and if run it not build it doesn't cause any errors, but if i build it on my local machine or onto heroku, it causes error. I found kludge, i just copy folder "views" from qor/admin rep and put it into my project folder by path  "app\views\qor". Now it works onto heroku, but, as i see in docs, it must be work without that folder.

Answer (score -1):

I found the method: You can just put the folder from the `qor/admin` repository into your project folder by path `<project_folder>/app/views/qor`. In the folder named `qor`, there must be `.tmpl` files and static-content folders.